# ADF Dynamic Tree Menu

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdeveloper

I am new to JDeveloper ADF framework. Is there any body who can help me to provide me any link where is described with DB Driven Dynamic Tree Menu???

Comment: Hello is there anybody to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are aiming to do, but it is quite trivial to create a tree component from data in your database. Then you can just replace the output text with af:link components to act as a menu.
Some tree help:
http://blogs.oracle.com/shay/2009/12/displaying_hierarchical_data_f.html
http://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/simple_hierarchy_viewer_search_with

An approach that might be interesting for you is to use dynamic regions:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/adf_dynamic_regions_switching_just

Comment: Actually my aim is role menu technique. I mean after login the user will see the menus which is permitted to view the menu. Other menus will hide

Answer (score 0):

Here you are http://www.yonaweb.be/creating_your_own_treemodel_adf_11g_0

Comment: @Shay Shmeltzer, Actually my aim is role menu technique. I mean after login the user will see the menus which is permitted to view the menu. Other menus will hide.